# How can I fix /a/downloads/ 404's on shopify?

Tags: http-status-code-404, shopify

So I'm receiving hundreds of broken 404 requests to a subfolder that is supposed to be post purchase on our shopify store.

```
/a/downloads/-/aad8e0b88e17cfa1/f59d7a91937c4056
/a/downloads/-/0205dea88b0a4b1f/553b2aa37fd08b58
/a/downloads/-/4b469e0946a8d4ad/c23af95e88ae680c
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken App. So look in your Apps and determine which one is providing the proxy. Open up the code, and look for the endpoint downloads, and start debugging. You will quickly determine your problem.